# Bitbucket issue creation link: pass in parameters?

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking

I'm using Bitbucket's Issue Collector for many projects. I usually set it to be private and give the testers an access to them + a direct link to the issue creation (i.e. `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<projectname>/issues/new`)

Is there any way that I could also pass in (via query params) the issue type being created?

I'd like to give them two links, one for creating bugs (something along the lines of `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<projectname>/issues/new?kind=bug&priority=minor`) and one for proposals (`https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<projectname>/issues/new?kind=proposal&priority=minor`)

I know I could change the different default issue type (currently bug), but I'd rather give the client two different links for two different reports.

The official documentation does not talk anywhere about query parameters being considered by this web page, so maybe it's not possible at all..

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Bitbucket developer, and I can confirm that what you're wanting to do only works for the title and description (which is called "content" in the query string).

E.g. https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/new?title=foo&content=bar

However, if you want to request that feature, that issue tracker I just linked to in my example is the official public issue tracker for Bitbucket itself.

Comment: Thanks @jnrbsn! I've submitted the proposal to the tracker. Link if anyone else finds this useful and wants to vote for it: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14035/create-issue-link-to-accept-kind-and